# Loss of data binding of a dependecy property

Tags: wpf, data-binding, dependency-properties

I have a custom control in which I created a custom `DependencyProperty` called `TheObject` that can contain a generic object.

```
<comp:MyControl TheObject="{Binding Country}" />
```

Sometimes, I need to set the `TheObject` internally (by code, internally to the control).

I did something like this:

```
this.TheObject = new Country();
```

But I realized that it is causing the loss of the `DataBinding` and the control becomes not responding to data changes.
What I really want is that this new object remains attached to the existing `DataBinding` of the property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`SetCurrentValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.setcurrentvalue.aspx):

> This method is used by a component that programmatically sets the value of one of its own properties without disabling an application's declared use of the property. The **SetCurrentValue** method changes the effective value of the property, but existing triggers, data bindings, and styles will continue to work.

```
this.SetCurrentValue(TheObjectProperty, new Country());
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked fine. I was trying to use the `SetValue` method.